# Haskell code to exclude numbers for Sieve of Eratosthenes not working as expected

Tags: algorithm, haskell, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I came with the following [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) implementation:

```haskell
sieve :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
sieve [] = []
sieve (p:ps) = p:[x | x <- sieve ps, (rem x p) /= 0] 

primes :: (Integral a) => [a]
primes = sieve [2..100]
```

Calling `primes` from `gchi` prints:

```
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
```

Adding the [optimization step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation) of starting marking numbers from **p<sup>2</sup>**, I ended up with the following code:

```haskell
sieve :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
sieve [] = []
sieve (p:ps) = p:[x | x <- sieve ps, x > p ^ 2, (rem x p) /= 0] 

primes :: (Integral a) => [a]
primes = sieve [2..100]
```

But it produces the following output:

```
[2]
```

I'm new to Haskell so I'm having problem to understand why adding the **`x > p ^ 2`** is producing this result.

Can you please spot my mistake by explaining how is Haskell doing the evaluation of that expression?

Comment: This is not the Sieve of Eratosthenes. It is a form of [trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) and will be slow. For a better functional sieve, see the [O'Neill sieve](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf), which is closely based on Eratosthenes.

Comment: I was concerned about the slowness of this implementation, that is why I was looking to skip the first `p^2` numbers, but as I learn through the answers, it doesn't work that way. Thanks for the paper link.

Comment: O'Neill's actual implementation is a little more complex (and much better) than the one in the paper. It's in [Math.Sieve.ONeill](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumberSieves-0.1.1/docs/Math-Sieve-ONeill.html) in the `NumberSieves` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
sieve [2..10]
```

Which expands to

```
2 : [x1 | x1 <- sieve [3..10], x1 > 4, rem x1 2 /= 0]
    = 2 : [x1 | x1 <- 3 : [x2 | x2 <- sieve [4..10],
                                x2 > 9,
                                x2 `rem` 3 /= 0],
                x1 > 4,
                x1 `rem` 2 /= 0]
```

So first `x1` is `3`, but `3 > 4` is `False` so we move to the next one:

```
    = 2 : [x1 | x1 <- [x2 | x2 <- sieve [4..10],
                            x2 > 9,
                            x2 `rem` 3 /= 0],
                x1 > 4,
                x1 `rem` 2 /= 0]

    = 2 : [x1 | x1 <- [x2 | x2 <- 4 : [x3 | x3 <- sieve [5..10],
                                            x3 > 16,
                                            x3 `rem` 4 /= 0],
                            x2 > 9,
                            x2 `rem` 3 /= 0],
                x1 > 4,
                x1 `rem` 2 /= 0]
```

So if `x2` is `4`, `x2 > 9` is false, so we move to the next element:

```
    = 2 : [x1 | x1 <- [x2 | x2 <- [x3 | x3 <- sieve [5..10],
                                        x3 > 16,
                                        x3 `rem` 4 /= 0],
                            x2 > 9,
                            x2 `rem` 3 /= 0],
                x1 > 4,
                x1 `rem` 2 /= 0]
```

So already we can see that the only actual value we know gets returned is `2`, `3` is skipped because `3 > 4` is `False`.  `4` gets skipped, but for the wrong reason, and `5` will get skipped because `5 > 16` is `False`, and so on.  The problem here is that your condition `x > p ^ 2` filters the entire list, but you really want to just jump ahead in your list.  This means that values you're actually interested in are getting filtered out from the output.

Comment: Thanks, really nice answer! Is there a way for jumping ahead in the list  using this approach or should I think of doing that in other way?

Comment: @higuaro as mentioned in the comment above by dfeuer you aren't actually implementing the sieve of eratosthenes with this style, it would be best to try a different route for finding prime numbers. List comprehensions do not allow you to jump ahead, they process each item in order.

Comment: @higuaro, as far as I know, the only (reasonably simple) way to jump ahead is to use a [wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization), a technique O'Neill explains much better in her paper. The problem with wheels seems to be that they get large rather quickly. Other approaches focus on chewing through the composites as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code:

```
p:[x | x <- sieve ps, x > p ^ 2, (rem x p) /= 0]
```

says "take all x from `sieve ps` such that  `x > p^2` and `x` is not divisible by `p`". Which means that all numbers less than or equal to `p^2` are thrown away. It is obviously not correct(the smallest counter example: `[2..3]`).